# How to call spring controller without submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I have a  section in my jsp. it looks like:

```
<select id="themeColor" class="form-control">
    <option>Black</option>
    <option selected>White</option>
</select>
```

and now i want to call my spring controller when i select another option. I do not want to reload a page, or go somewhere. Just a controller call, which would do some actions in the DB.

Is this possible at all?

Oh, list of used instruments: spring MVC, bootstrap.css and js, and jQuery

Comment: Ajax call is the answer see answer by @Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is to make an ajax call to your controller.  What you do with that retrieved data is up to you.

For example, culled from a real life example...

```
$('#themeColor').change(function() {
   var theme = $(this).val();
   changeTheme(theme);
});

function changeTheme(theme) {

    var data = {
            theme : theme
    };

    var url = "mySpringContoller.html";

    $.ajax( {
        type : "POST",
        url : url,
        data : data
    }).done(function(returnedData) {
            // Do something cool here with the returnedData.
    }).fail(function(returnedData) {
        // Do something not so cool here with the returnedData;
    }).always(function(returnedData) {
        // Always do something if you want to. 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is in the form you can post the form programmatically to controller action on change of selection of dropdownlist like this:

```
$('#themeColor').change(function(){

$(this).closest("form").submit();


})
```